# Resizable TextArea upto a certain size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a text area field in Angular4/Bootstrap3 to be run on IE11.

The text area will be pre-filled with some text

```
<textarea [value]="mydata" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
```

This works the way one would expect it to. 5 rows are shown and if text exceeds what can be fitted into 5 rows, a scrollbar is displayed. If text is less than empty space is displayed in the text area.

What I am trying to achieve is little different than the default behavior. I would like the textarea to be resizable but the size should not exceed certain number of rows. Lets say the max size is set to 5 rows. 
So, if the text to be displayed can be fitted in 1 row, then text area only shows 1 row. If it can be fitted in 4 rows it expands to 4 rows. If it can be fitted in 10 rows, then it expands up to 5 rows and shows a scrollbar for the remaining text.

Is such kind of behaviour possible? I have used rows as an example, but if it can be achieved with height property or something else, I am fine with that as well.

Comment: When you have text that originally fits 10 rows, and you limit it to 5 rows, you will get a horizontal overflow. Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. However, for text less than 5 rows I don't want to display 5 rows (with lots of empty space). I want the text area to expand upto 5 rows (depending on the amount of text) and then show a scrollbar, if there is more.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a little CSS, and using the `max-height` property:

```
textarea {
    overflow-y:scroll
    max-height:100px; /* change to a height you see fit */
}
```

By not setting a default height, the text area will be high enough for any content less than your `max-height`, and when it hits it, it'll start scrolling.

Also, remove the `rows` attribute from your `textarea`.

Comment: Thank you. Even if there is just one word to display, the text area still shows up with multiple rows (seems rows has some default value). Also, when the text increases, it doesn't expand the text area to max-height, rather puts a scrollbar in the default size text area.

Comment: take the `rows` attribute away - the textarea will then default to one row :)